# How to store user information in php and then display it in a table

Tags: php, html, authentication, html-table, credentials

I am trying to create a table of login credentials. I have a login button that takes usernames and passwords and is able to send them via POST. I would like to display the information in an html table. My index.html looks like this:

```
<html><head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body style="left:-1px; top:-2px; " >
<form action="index.html" method="post" >
Email<input type="email" name="data" value="" />
Password<input type="text" name="pass" value="" />
<input type="submit" />

<?php 
$index = 0;
$credentials = array{usernames,};
if (isset($_POST['submit']) { //to check if the form was submitted
    $username= $_POST['data'];
     $password= $_Post['pass'];
    //$result = array($username,$password);

    $credentials['usernames'].append($username);
    $credentials['passwords'].append($password);


    }
?>


</form>
<table>
<tbody><tr><th>Usernames</th>
<th>Passwords</th>
<?php for($i = 0; $i < $credentials.length; $i++){ <tr><?php echo $credentials[i]?></tr><tr><?php echo $credentials[password[i]]?></tr><tr>
</body><html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For starters it looks like you're trying to use PHP like javascript.

Comment: There are several syntax errors in your code. `$credentials = array{usernames,};` will cause an error as will `$credentials['usernames'].append($username);`. See http://de1.php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php

Comment: this script will run each time a user submits a page. I.e. there will only ever be one username password available per submission of the page. You need to save the user/pass pairs somewhere (textfile or database) if your want to display a table of them.
A few syntax errors in your code, and beware of capITALisation ($_POST not $_Post)

Answer (score 0):

First, your form action points to an HTML file. If you expect to use PHP, use a .php file extension. That's your first problem, right there. An HTML file cannot parse PHP.

Second, If you want to parse passwords, play safe and use PHP.
Then, consider a php while loop to list each $_POST, like so:

```
echo '<table>';
while (list($key,$value) = each($_POST)) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td><td>'.html_entity_decode(stripslashes($value)).'</td></td>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

You should be able to view the information properly, regardless of the number of items in your form.

Comment: Okay so I used your code in my index.php file. Now I have two files. One Html file that looks like my initial code without the php in it. The index.php code is yours above besides that $key is instead $data and $value is instead $pass. While trying to run the code, the php is not working. It comes up in clear text. How do I get it to run?

Comment: play safe and add this to show all errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` It will tell you half of what's going wrong

Comment: Okay so that worked and now it is displaying a blank page. This is good except for the fact that nothing is displayed.     <?php

        while (list($email,$pass) = each($_POST)) {
            echo '';
        }
        echo '<table><tbody><tr><td>'$email'</td><td>'$pass'</td></tr></tbody></table>';
  
        error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ?>

Comment: always start with error reporting, it will show all errors it encounters, whereas at the end, it won't show anything before. Also, within your while loop, I suggest something like: `if(empty($pass)) { echo 'pass is empty<br />'; }`. It will tell you if it is empty. If it is a coding error, you will see it due to error reporting early in your document.

Comment: thanks for your help. I wasn't running apache (duh). I think I understand it a lot better now.